# Validating format of 2 controls

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using custom validation control to check if any one of the 2 phone numbers (HomePhone Textbox and BusinessPhone Textbox) are filled or not on my form.

I am able to do it by using JavaScript.

Now I want to check the format of the phone number entered by using regular expression validation control. But the problem I am facing is in "ControlToValidate" property.

As any one of the textboxes can be filled by the users, which control I should validate?

If I am not clear let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a separate regular expression validation control for each text field, unfortunately. You set the ControlToValidate to each text box on each validation control

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way? But for now, if its the only way, its working.

Comment: @rapsalands the other ways is not using asp.net controls and use jQuery or plain Javascript

Comment: can you help me out with some code snippets...it will be great in Javascript....but if not, no worries I will try to figure ir out